# ascending and descending table - Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort my table in an *ascending* and *descending* orders when you click on the little button beside the heading of the table.

It should sort itself out alphabetically and the date in years.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Following is my code

```js
var table = $(".main").append("<table></table>");
var thead = '<thead><tr></tr></thead>';
table.append(thead);
var header = [{
  title: 'Name',
  sortBy: 'name'
}, {
  title: 'Last Name',
  sortBy: 'lastName'
}, {
  title: 'Date of birth',
  sortBy: 'dob'
}].map(
  function(header) {
    var sortButton = '<button id="' + header.sortBy + '" onclick=sortRows("' + header.sortBy + '")>/\\</button>';
    $('thead').append('<th>' + header.title + ' ' + sortButton + '</th>');
  }
)
var tbody = "<tbody></tbody>";
var data = [{
  name: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Petterson',
  dob: '13/12/1988'
}, {
  name: 'Anna',
  lastName: 'Jones',
  dob: '06/02/1968'
}, {
  name: 'John',
  lastName: 'Milton',
  dob: '01/06/2000'
}, {
  name: 'James',
  lastName: 'White',
  dob: '30/11/1970'
}, {
  name: 'Luke',
  lastName: 'Brown',
  dob: '15/08/1999'
}];

$('.search').change(function(event) {
  searchedName = event.target.value;
})
table.append(tbody);
draw();

function draw() {
  $('tbody').html('');
  data.map(
    function(row, i) {
      $('tbody').append(
        '<tr><td>' + row.name +
        '</td><td>' + row.lastName +
        '</td><td>' + row.dob +
        '</td><td><button onclick=editRow(' + i + ')>edit</button><button onclick=delRow(' + i + ') >delete</button></td></tr>'
      )
    }
  )
}
var editRow = function(rowNumber) {

  var editableRow = "<td><input id='name'/></td><td><input id='lastName'/></td><td><input id='dob' type='date'/></td><td><button onclick=saveRow(" + rowNumber + ")>save</button></td>";
  var name = $('tbody > tr:nth-child(' + (rowNumber + 1) + ') > td:first-child').text();
  var lastName = $('tbody > tr:nth-child(' + (rowNumber + 1) + ') > td:nth-child(2)').text();
  var dob = $('tbody > tr:nth-child(' + (rowNumber + 1) + ') > td:nth-child(3)').text();

  $('tbody > tr:nth-child(' + (rowNumber + 1) + ')').html(editableRow);
  $('tbody > tr:nth-child(' + (rowNumber + 1) + ') > td:first-child > input').val(name);
  $('tbody > tr:nth-child(' + (rowNumber + 1) + ') > td:nth-child(2) > input').val(lastName);
  $('tbody > tr:nth-child(' + (rowNumber + 1) + ') > td:nth-child(3) > input').val(dob);
}
var sortRows = function(sortBy) {
  isAscending[sortBy] = !isAscending[sortBy];
  $('#' + sortBy).text(isAscending[sortBy] ? '\\/' : '/\\');
};

var delRow = function(num) {

  data.splice(num, 1);
  draw();
}

var addPerson = function() {
  isNewLineToggled = !isNewLineToggled;
  if (isNewLineToggled) {
    $('tbody').prepend('<tr>' + editableRow + '</tr>')
  } else {
    $('tbody > tr:first-child').remove();
  }
}

var saveRow = function(num) {

  data[num].name = $('#name').val();
  data[num].lastName = $('#lastName').val()
  data[num].dob = $('#dob').val();
  draw();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: I would recommend using jQuery's extension datatables: https://datatables.net/  Easy ordering & pagination

Comment: You should really check out the datatables. They are great and fully customized to be use as per needs.

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: isAscending is not defined"`  

Where did you define isAscending?